# Objective C to Swift bridging <<error type>>

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

I have Objective-C class, which I want to use in Swift. I use it with singleton `sharedInstance` and shortcut which was created in swift. But when I type this shortcut, I see `<<error type>>` in autocomplete and no color syntax and no autocompletion helping.

If I call any function on this shortcut, such as `TripPlannerKit.tripName` app will work fine, but it is really hard to type when you have huge methods.

How to import Objective-C with full syntax support?

[image]

My briding file is really simple

```
#import "Project-Prefix.pch"

#import "TripPlannerManager.h"
```

And this is my `Global.swift` where I create shortcuts for using Objective-C singletons

```
import Foundation

//=== managers & kits

let TripPlannerKit = TripPlannerManager.sharedInstance()
```

Comment: Add a bridging header maybe?

Comment: @Sweeper updated. But really nothing intresting

Comment: You should be confused with compilation errors, not with that Xcode's buggy swift autocompleation

Comment: @Cy-4AH everything ok with compilation, but not with real-time autocopleation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it!

```
Product -> Clean
Product -> (Alt+) Clean, for Clean Build Folder
Window -> Projects -> Choose your project -> Delete derived data
```

Then your project will be reindexed by XCode and everything will work.

Comment: Product -> (Alt+) Clean, for Clean Build Folder was enough for me ! thanks !